# Graph Subscriptions Beta - AdditionalData

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

in the Graph Beta Subscriptions API, there is a property that can be set or got on the Subscription object called AdditionalData.
I am trying to use this when creating a subscription to transport data that will be sent back with change notifications and provide more context to my task.
I am finding though that even though I set the property, it does not keep my added dictionary items but replaces with its own additional data.
Not sure if I am using this property for something that I shouldn't be or whether this is a bug or am I just setting it wrong? I am doing something like this:

```
         var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            Resource = $"users/{userObjectId}/mailFolders('{resource}')/messages",
            ChangeType = "created",
            NotificationUrl = notificationWebHookUrl,
            LifecycleNotificationUrl = lifecycleNotificationWebHookUrl,
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "test", "123"} },
            ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4200, 0)
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription object doesn't support storing additional data. You can have custom data passed back to your notification URL when notifications are being delivered two ways:

- You can include some of that data in the `clientState`, although this property is designed to be used as a security feature, you can put anything you want in there.
- Any query string parameter included in the notification URL will be passed back when notifications are being delivered. I just authored [a pull request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/9316) to add that missing information.

Comment: Thanks. We started off using the client state but discovered that it is limited to 128 characters. This wasn't sufficient for our purposes. URL query strings will probably come up against the same issue.

Comment: The URL is supposed to be able to hold much more. Can I suggest you try it out and see whether it covers your scenario?

Comment: Actually one more question, will the query string params also come through to the Lifecycle url or just the notification url?

Comment: I believe the parameters set for each should come to the respective URLs when delivering notifications.